# How to update QGridLayout row/column count depending on the layout size?

Tags: qt, user-interface, layout, qtwidgets

This thing seems really basic to me, though I could not find any information on how to implement it.

I have some sort of `QGridLayout` that contains equally-sized widgets. I would like to update its row/column count based on the layout size.

For instance, on a relatively wide screen, it would look like this:

[image: wide screen]

But if the screen is not wide enough to fit all the items it would grow vertically like this:

[image: narrow screen]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `QGridLayout` doesn't support this automatically. You can either:

1. Use `QGridLayout` with a number of columns set according to screen width divided by the widget width, and the number of rows sufficient to fit the widgets, or
2. Use the [flow layout example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) and modify to your needs.